# how to access stdclass object in an arrray in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i have a function in model in codeignitor

```
     public function show_list()
{

    $query = $this->db->get('area_list');
    $area_list = $query->result();

    return $area_list;
}
```

then i have a function  in controller to use the function of the model

```
     public function showarea()
{

    $area_list = $this->area_model->show_list();
    $data = [];
    foreach ( $area_list as $area ) {
        $data[] = $area;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

and a jquery function

```
        function show_table(){
    $.post("http://localhost/crm/index.php/areaController/showarea",function(data){
    alert(data);
            });

            };
```

now  its showing like that when i get return data in jquery

```
                           [
    {"area_id":"1","area_name":"North","area_desc":"north",
    "area_created":"2016-04-11 14:02:05"}, 
      {"area_id":"2","area_name":"South","area_desc":"no", 
     "area_created":"2016-04-09 18:44:05"}
    ]

or like 


     Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [area_id] => 1 [area_name] => North [area_desc]
        => Mirpur 1 [area_created] => 2016-04-11 14:02:05 )

   [1] => stdClass Object ( [area_id] => 2 [area_name] => North area_desc]=>
  area_desc [area_created] => 2016-04-09 18:44:15 )

  [2] => stdClass Object ( [area_id] => 3 [area_name] => west [area_desc] =>
 west [area_created] => 2016-04-10 19:34:27 ) 

 )
```

so can anyone suggest me how can i get the value of area_name ,area_desc by jquery !

Comment: `data[index].area_name`? for example `data[0].area_name`

Comment: showing undefined   @ Sandeep Nayak

Comment: You need to use `$.parseJSON(data);` before using `data`;

Comment: i had tried this before but dont know why did not get the result as now !

Comment: Have you tried in show list $query->result_array();

Comment: thank' to   @ itzmukeshy7 its done !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Replace your function `show_list()` with the following function

```
<?php   
public function show_list()
{

    $query = $this->db->get('area_list');
    $area_list = $query->result_array();

    return $area_list;
}
?>
```

Step 2: replace you script function `show_table()` with this code

```
<script>
function show_table()
{

    $.post("http://localhost/crm/index.php/areaController/showarea",function(data){
        if(data != null)
        {
            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                alert(val['area_id']);
                alert(val['area_name']);
                alert(val['area_desc']);
            });
        }   
     });
}
</script>
```

This will resolve your problem, Try this and let me know, if any error you got...